# Is there a name for a container "C a" that holds either an "a" or a function returning a value of type "C a"?

Tags: haskell

AKA partial application as a container type.

I've been writing a parser / expression evaluator that takes a list of definitions such as `"a = b + 2c", "c = b + d", "d = 2b"`, and an expression like `"-a + 3b + c"` and simplifies it to a single term by repeatedly applying one or more of the definitions like so:

```
"-a + 3b + c" -> "-(b + 2c) + 3b + c" by "a = b + 2c"
"-(b + 2c) + 3b + c" -> "-(b + 2(b + d)) + 3b + b + d" by "c = b + d"
"-(b + 2(b + d)) + 3b + b + d" -> "-(b + 2(b + 2b)) + 3b + b + 2b" by "d = 2b"
"-(b + 2(b + 2b)) + 3b + b + 2b" -> "-b" by evaluation
```

In order to easily "apply" definitions to the expression, I came up with the data type and accompanying functions:

```hs
data Expr = Imm Int Char
          | Par ((Char, Expr) -> Expr)

applyToExpr :: (Char, Expr) -> Expr -> Expr
applyToExpr (Imm n v) (c, ast) = if v == c then mul n ast else Imm n v
applyToExpr (Par f) d = f d

mul :: Int -> Expr -> Expr
mul c (Imm n v) = Imm (c*n) v
mul c a = Par (mul c . applyToExpr a)

add :: Expr -> Expr -> Expr
add a b
  | Imm an ac <- a
  , Imm bn bc <- b
  , ac == bc = Imm (an + bn) ac
  | otherwise = Par (\d -> add (applyToExpr a d) (applyToExpr b d)) 

-- Plus similar functions for subtraction, negation, etc
```

In other words, an Expr is either a concrete value or its a function that takes in a definition and returns another Expr. Usage and creation are fairly straightforward, you get a sort of "function tree", where you apply a definition to the "root" and it propagates that definition down the tree, reducing and combining terms as it goes. You know you are done when the "root" is an `Imm Int Char` and that's your answer.

More generally, you could imagine a type

```hs
data Partial a b = Imm b
                 | Par (a -> Partial a b)
```

and some values

```
num :: Partial Int Int
num = Imm 3

adder2 :: Partial Int Int
adder2 = Par (\n -> Par (\m -> Imm (n+m)))
```

that might have some interesting properties.

The problem is that, while `Imm` values are easy to inspect, `Par` values are fairly opaque. You can't really write a `Show` instance for `Expr`, nor can you really walk the "tree" and get a feel for what it looks like at any given time. I got around the `Show` problem by hackily adding a `String` field to `Par` that represents a stringified version of its contents at any given time, but this is brittle and tedious to deal with.

It feels like this is the kind of thing that has been done before, so I've been looking around at various data structures to see if there is a polymorphic one that does essentially what I am trying to do, but I haven't found anything quite right.

The concept is sort of similar to a Continuation, but not quite.

It also has similarities to the Either monad.

So my question is: **Is there a name for this general pattern? If not, is there a way to restructure this to make it easier to inspect and extend?**

Comment: Similar, but not identical, to a "resumption" monad. A similar trick is used in the common representation of "pure IO", where IO effects are described with a simple coinductive monad `data PureIO a = Done a | Output String (PureIO a) | Input (String -> PureIO a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Partial a` is the [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free) for the functor `(->) a` (aka. "reader"). (And the view of free monads as (syntax) trees is common, if not the very point of it.)

```hs
data Free f b
  = Pure b
  | Join (f (Free f b))

-- (Partial a) is equivalent to Free ((->) a)
-- N.B.  (->) a c = (a -> c)

data Partial a b
  = Imm b
  | Par (a -> Partial a b)
```